# SMC is in U mode, not in A mode

Tags: macbook-pro, power-management

On a Late 2008 MacBook Pro with a dead battery, i have a SMC issue that popped out.
My fans are at 100%, no keyboard backlit, the usual SMC story.

I've tried the usual technique from the Internet to reset the SMC plus the SMCFlasher tool, but no success.

Until now, each time i've had the SMC problem, the only working solution for my was: **Left Shift + Option + Ctrl + Power.**

Now, if i use that technique, the notebook shuts down and the only way to start it again is to Press PWR 10 seconds without the power cord, 10 seconds again with the power cord plugged in, and then a simple push of Power Button.

Any other ideas ?

[image: SMC dmesg]

[image: SMCFlasher error]